# Is it safe to drop and then create the foreign key constraints inside a transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, foreign-keys, populate

I have a table A that references a table B. Table B needs to be populated with updated data from an external source and for efficiency I use TRUNCATE followed by a COPY. This is done even when the application is live.

To further improve efficiency, [as suggested in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/populate.html), I want to drop and then recreate the foreign keys.

However I have some doubts.

If I drop the FKs, COPY and then recreate FKs **inside the same transaction**, can I be sure that the constraint is preserved even on data inserted in table A during the transaction? I ask this because in theory a transaction is atomic, but in the docs, about the temporary removal of FKs say:

> there is a trade-off between data load speed and loss of error checking while the constraint is missing.

If there's a chance that a wrong reference is inserted in the meantime, what happens when you try to recreate the FK constraints?

Comment: How many rows in the B table are actually changed by the import? How many are inserted? How many deleted? (hint: if A references B, then after the import all the referenced keys in B must still be present; new keys may appear and dont have to be referenced by A yet)

Comment: @joop In B there are about 13M of rows that need to be refreshed. In case in B there are some referenced rows the get removed, I've added an UPDATE to set the references to NULL inside the same transaction, just before recreating the FKs.

Comment: It is not about the actual rows that are to be deleted/updated inserted, but about the **keys**. What is the proportion of keys that is added/removed ? (and secondary: if the key *is* the same in B and new_B: what is the proportion of records in which the *attributes* actually change value?)

Comment: @wildplasser Good question: I don't know, but I can tell you that I am trying to refresh data from the weekly Wikidata dump. I import most of the items, applying some changes to adapt them to my schema.

Comment: If you don't know: *measure* it. (for Wikipedia dump, I presume most of the records don't actually change, and inserts will be rather rare) Are the keys stable? (otherwise: consider a data-vault-like model) I'll add an answer (which is more or less analytic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` is not allowed on any table referenced by a foreign key, unless you use `TRUNCATE CASCADE`, which will also truncate the referencing tables. The `DEFERRABLE` status of the constraint does not affect this. I don't think there is any way around this; you will need to drop the constraint.

However, there is no risk of an integrity violation in doing so. `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT` locks the table in question (as does `TRUNCATE`), so your import process is guaranteed to have exclusive access to the table for the duration of its transaction. Any attempts at concurrent inserts will simply hang until the import has committed, and by the time they are allowed to proceeed, the constraint will be back in place.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the foreign key constraint [deferrable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) (initially deferred). That way it will be checked just once at the end of the transaction.

```
ALTER TABLE
  xxx
ADD CONSTRAINT
  xxx_yyy_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (yyy_id)
REFERENCES
  yyy
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

In all the cases, transactions are fully atomic in PostgreSQL (not only in theory), including DDL statements (such as CREATE/DROP constraint), so even if you drop a foreign key, then insert data, then create the foreign key and do everything in one transaction, then you are safe - if the recreation of the foreign key constraint fails, then the inserted data will also be dismissed.

Still, it is better to switch to deferred foreign keys, rather than dropping and then creating them.

Comment: Since the transaction takes about 20 minutes (since there is some ETL involved in the data which is COPYed), I'm wondering what happens to someone who tries in the meantime to insert a row with a reference...

Comment: Then I don't know if the method you suggest is acceptable for millions of rows. I think that drop and recreate is different from deferring the checking: have you read [paragraph 14.4.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/populate.html)?

Comment: Well, it depends on your current situation and needs. Dropping a foreign key will create an `Access Exclusive Lock` on **both** tables (the referencing and the referenced). That means that while your transaction is processing, even a single SELECT will be blocked on both tables. So if you do not care for concurrency, you can safely go for the drop-insert-create scenario (in one transaction). Otherwise deferring the constraint will be a lot better, as it will create only `Row Exclusive Lock` only over the referencing table.

Comment: As for the list of pending trigger events and a possible lack of memory issue, I am not certain how deferred constraints interact with it, i.e. whether there is difference between normal and deferred constraints. Perhaps you can monitor the memory usage by testing both approaches and share the results?

Answer (score 1):

Analytic answer: measure the number of new/same/updated/deleted records.
There are four cases:

- The key in the `B` table is not present in the b_import: delete
- The key in the `b_import` is not present on the old B: insert
- The key is present in both old B and new B, but the contents are the same: ignore
- The keys are the same, but the attribete values differ: Update

---

```
        -- some test data for `A`, `B` and `B_import`:
CREATE TABLE b
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , payload varchar
        );
INSERT INTO b(id,payload) SELECT gs, 'bb_' || gs::varchar
FROM generate_series(1,20) gs;

CREATE TABLE b_import
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , payload varchar
        );
INSERT INTO b_import(id,payload) SELECT gs, 'bb_' || gs::varchar
FROM generate_series(10,15) gs;
        -- In real life this table will be filled by a `COPY b_import FROM ...`
INSERT INTO b_import(id,payload) SELECT gs, 'b2_' || gs::varchar
FROM generate_series(16,25) gs;

CREATE TABLE a
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , b_id INTEGER references b(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
        , aaaaa varchar
        );
INSERT INTO a(b_id,aaaaa)
SELECT gs,'aaaaa_' || gs::text FROM generate_series(1,20) gs;
CREATE INDEX ON a(b_id); -- index supporting the FK

        -- show it
SELECT a.id, a.aaaaa
        ,b.id, b.payload AS oldpayload
FROM a
FULL JOIN b ON a.b_id=b.id
ORDER BY a.id;

        -- Do the actual I/U/D and report the numbers of affected rows
-- EXPLAIN
WITH ins AS (   -- INSERTS
        INSERT INTO b(id, payload)
        SELECT b_import.id, b_import.payload
        FROM b_import
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM b
                WHERE b.id = b_import.id
                )
        RETURNING b.id
        )
, del AS (      -- DELETES
        DELETE FROM b
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 2 FROM b_import
                WHERE b_import.id  = b.id
                )
        RETURNING b.id
        )
, upd AS (      -- UPDATES
        UPDATE b
        SET payload=b_import.payload
        FROM b_import
        WHERE b_import.id = b.id
        AND b_import.payload IS DISTINCT FROM b.payload -- exclude idempotent updates
        -- AND NOT EXISTS (     -- exclude deleted records
                -- SELECT 3 FROM del
                -- WHERE del.id = b_import.id
                -- )
        -- AND NOT EXISTS (     -- avoid touching freshly inserted rows
                -- SELECT 4 FROM ins
                -- WHERE ins.id = b_import.id
                -- )
        RETURNING b.id
        )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS orgb
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b_import) AS newb
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ins) AS ninserted
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM del) AS ndeleted
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM upd) AS nupdated
FROM b
        ;
```

---

- Dropping a constraint and rebuilding it after the import is expensive: *all* the records in both `A` and `B` are involved.
- temporally ignoring the constraint is *dangerous*: the new `B` table could miss some rows that are still referenced by `A`'s FK.
- ergo: You could end up with a crippled model, and you'd have to rebuild `A`s references (which is basically impossible, without additional information (which would be redundant, BTW))